# Can't reach admin panel after migrating prestashop from one host to another

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I moved one prestashop site from one host to another. What I make is this:

```
1. Copy all the files from the host -> Paste them into new host
2. Export database from old host -> Import into database on new host
3. Then I change values in config/settings.inc.php
4. Change values with the new domain in database table ps_shop_url -> domain, domain_ssl, physical_url
5. Change values in database table ps_configuration -> PS_SHOP_DOMAIN and PS_SHOP_DOMAIN_SSL
```

.htaccess is also changed according to new host:

`before - RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/presta/]`

`after - RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/]`

Now the shop seems to work except some images but when I try to open admin panel http://example.com/admin324r498 I got 404 error page.

What can be the problem?

Comment: when you call full url http://example.com/admin324r498/index.php what you get? also 404?

Comment: Yes, still 404 error.

Comment: I have tried same procedure and to move shop to localhost and there is no problems at all. So the problem is in the host may be? What can be the problem on the another host? I can ask the support to fix it.

Comment: yes, now it looks like host related issue

Comment: Yes, it is.. since I'm able to move it on my local. But what can be the problem?

Comment: Was your issue solved?  If yes, would be great if you could answer your own question so this doesn't show up as un-answered and others can learn from it too. (or you can delete the question if it's to much work for you) Thanks for your understanding and cooperation.

Comment: @Trevor thank's for the suggestion. I will answering briefly since there is not so much what to do and was long time ago and I didn't remember exact steps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was in the new hosting provider and the permissions of the files while I copy files between two hosts.

I talk with them(my hosting provider) and they told me that there is "no problem on their end"...

The solution was to change manually every single file permission on the host via `File manager` or to install new prestashop directly on the host and then upload `sql` dump file and theme files etc.. or as last solution -> change the host provider.